# Sharepoint calculated columns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i have predefined list of data, which contains data for each date, now i would like to sum each column on a week basis (to retrieve weekly sum of data for each column)
I tried using week number formula for each day how ever i cannot sum the data using the week number

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the list or list schema?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your "Week number" formula is.

I suppose that you have a "Week number" calculated field with the formula below to get the week number of the date in the year.

```
INT(([date]-DATE(YEAR([date]),1,1)+(TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR([a2]),1,1)),"d")))/7)
```

It would be better to get the week of the date if you have different years of date.

For example: form Monday to Sunday

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT([date]-(WEEKDAY([date],2)-1),"mm/dd/yyyy")," - ",TEXT([date]+(7-WEEKDAY([date],2)),"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

To get sum values based on the week, you can create/modify a list view and group by "Week" or "Week number" field. It will group items together based on the "Week"/"Week number" value.

Then, sum value.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Calculated columns can only calculate (selected) fields from the item itself. It's a little unclear to me if you want to calculate across several items. If that is the case the suggestion from JoannaW_MSFT is the easiest way to sum - however it's hardly the prettiest way to do it.

Another way would be to write a simple javascript which uses the rest API to retrieve all list items and do a sum on them. I does require a bit more work on your end, and if not familiar with rest and/or javascript it can be a bit daunting/frustrating at first.

If you decide to use the rest API i suggest you start here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest